# Following google "I'm feeling lucky" redirect with httpURLConnection

Tags: java, redirect, httpurlconnection

I want to get the URL that the I'm feeling lucky button redirects to (aka the first result). I pass in the url:

http://www.google.com/search?&btnI=745&pws=0&q=hello

which by now, goes to http://www.hellomagazine.com/

The problem is that the server responds with code 200 (OK) instead of 302 (redirection), so I don't know how the redirection is being performed, nor how to get the final URL.

This is the code I've been trying:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)wikiURL.openConnection(); 
            connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.76");
            connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(15000);
            connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            connection.connect();

            System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode());
            System.out.println(connection.getHeaderField("Location"));
```

This is the output:

```
200
null
```

Edit: The problem seems to be the url itself. It works with the one I posted here, but not with this one, for instance:

"http://www.google.com/search?&btnI=745&pws=0&q=%2Bfutebolista+%2Bwikipedia+Marcio+Gabriel,+Atlético-GO"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was encoding, had to force UTF-8. I was showing me 200 code because there were no results found when searching for things with latin characters that weren't properly encoded

Answer (score 2):

If I run your code, I get this output:

```
302
http://www.hellomagazine.com/
```

If I set

```
connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
```

then I can read the full Hello website from the

```
connection.getInputStream()
```

If I leave it as false, i.e. not follow redirects, then the output is:

```
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.hellomagazine.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Which is a little wierd, coz the header you are reading isn't actually set!  You could parse that body though and look for the HREF when you get a 302, if it still isn't working for you.

If you are still getting a 200 response, then try this and let us know what the output is please:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

I also setup Eclipse's TCP/IP Monitor so that I could see exactly what was being sent over the wire.

Comment: Ok, actually your answer made me test what I hadn't. The url I posted on the question was not the real one because I assumed the problem wasn't there. Apparently, it is there. As you said, testing it with the original url produces a 302 response. Now, try with this one:

http://www.google.com/search?&btnI=745&pws=0&q=%2Bfutebolista+%2Bwikipedia+Marcio+Gabriel,+Atlético-GO

Why is it throwing a response code 200 now? (I edited the question)

Answer (score 1):

```
connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
```

is your problem.  You want this to be false because you don't want to auto-follow redirects; you want to retrieve the notification of the re-direct.

Comment: Sorry, in fact it was false when I ran it. Changed it later just for testing purposes. Thanks for pointing out the mistake. But the question still remains as it was :)